# How to filter results by included models?

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm facing a problem on querying filtered results with sequelize, description below.

User model:

```
var User = db.define('User', {
  email: {
    type: types.STRING,
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: types.STRING
  },
  firstName: {
    type: types.STRING
  },
  lastName: {
    type: types.STRING
  },
  type: {
    type: types.INTEGER
  }
});
```

User services model:

```
var UserServices = db.define('UserServices', {
  service: {
    type: types.INTEGER
  }
});


var Countries = db.define('Countries', {
  name: {
    type: types.STRING
  },
  code: {
    type: types.STRING(10)
  }
});
```

Relationships:

```
User.hasMany(UserServices);
UserServices.belongsTo(User);

Countries.hasMany(User);
User.belongsTo(Countries);
```

Question following: how to filter out only those users belonging to a specified country, having specific services and a specified user type?

What I'm trying to do now is following (doesn't work as expected):

```
User.findAll({
  where: {
    type: 3
  },
  inlcude: [{
    model: Countries,
    where: {
      id: 2
    }
  }, {
    model: UserServices,
    where: {
      service: [1, 2, 3]
    }
  }]
}).then((user) => {
...
})
```

Comment: This should work. And you should be using in operator for service